# how to count unique values by certain criteria?

Tags: excel

Say if I had the following sample table:

```
Country     Year
USA         2010
USA         2010
USA         2010
Australia   2011
India       2010
China       2010

Output should be:
2010: 3 (USA, India, and China)
2011: 1 (Australia)
2012: 0 ()
```

I am trying to count the unique number of countries during a certain year.

I having trouble how to get the nested conditional count working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
I cannot use VBA, i must use native excel functions or pivot tables.

Comment: fixed the table, didnt notice it was outputting wrong before.

Comment: Pivot table didn't work?

Comment: i couldnt think of a way to do it with pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get some way there by concatenating Year&Country and then do a count within a pivottable. The only problem is that you can't get a zero. This also won't lay it out in the way it looks like you want but is that important?

If so, then a formula might help which would list unique entries in a range (again utilising the concatenated column)......

I have developed a formula which does this using countif:

[image: COUNTIF example]

Hope this help you or someone else need to list and count unique values.

Just adding a link to share the excel file I've created.  Enjoy.  [Excel file](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2wPZjiQ_eFlZHF6cDNVV0U3VWs&usp=sharing%3E)

Comment: Well, if you provide link to an image this is hardly a solution. Image will be removed after some time and there will be no anwser to this question. Next time try to paste formulas in your awnsers. I found link like this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-occurrences-of-values-or-unique-values-in-a-data-range-HP003056118.aspx

Comment: Hi Iowak, good point about the image link - I would have like to have added my excel file here but doesn't look as if you can do that.  The formulas i've created are complex and require the rest of the data to be shown so I thought that that would be the best way.  There are may ways to skin a cat I must admit and using FREQUENCY is probably a good alternate but I'm not sure how you pull out the labels too.  My solution covers that.  Please let me know if there is a way to add an excel file here.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste your data into a new worksheet to allow you to play with it.

Remove Duplicates (Data>Data Tools>Remove Duplicates) based on country and year.

Then sort ascending with filter based on year (Data>Sort & Filter).

Then subtotal a count (Data>Outline>Subtotal) based on change in year.